# Сбрасывание скролла

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Есть небольшой скрипт табов. Но когда есть скролл и ты где-то внизу и переключаешься на другой таб, то скролл сбрасывается. Эффект получается, как будто кнопки переключпния табов - ссылке, в которых `href="#"`.
Там всего много в плане оформления, поэтому закинул [сюда](http://jsfiddle.net/inferusvv/qh5Pc/).

Comment: Писать код в одну строчку удобно? )) И сделали б котнента побольше, чтобы тот самый скролл, который вас смущает, был виден. Ну, хоть [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qh5Pc/1/). А теперь бы понять, как можно переключать закладки, находясь при этом "где-то внизу"?

Comment: @Deonis Я о другом. Я про контент на странице. Если табы находятся где то по середине и я начинаю переключать, то скролл "сбрасывается" вверх

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно [запретить](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) вызывание стандартного события по клику (сейчас это переход по якорю "#", то есть в начало страницы):

```
 $('ul.tabs').delegate('li:not(.box_current)', 'click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      ...
```

(обращаю ваше внимание на появление параметра "e" у функции)

Comment: не, не помогло. якорей нет. Это я для примера описал эффект.

Comment: Да, поспешишь — людей насмешишь. Вы сначала убираете весь контент после меню, страница съезжает до этого меню, а затем добавляете и страница не съезжает обратно.

Чтобы этого не происходило, нужно сначала показывать контент, а затем скрывать ненужный: http://jsfiddle.net/qh5Pc/2/

Comment: @caravaneer А можно добавить эффект fadeOut для тех табов, что убираются?

Comment: Да, можно. 
Чтобы блоки не скакали друг под другом при появлении/скрытии, нужно добавить следующие правила:
.widget_tabs { position: relative }
.tabs_box { position: absolute; top: 39px; }

Ну и не забыть поменять hide() на fadeOut()

Comment: @caravaneer а не поможешь с fadeOut(), пожалуйста?

Comment: а в чём проблема? http://jsfiddle.net/qh5Pc/3/

Answer (score 0):

Да местами поменяйте скрытие не активных блоков и открытие текущего и как бы всё. [Смотрим тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qh5Pc/4/)

```
var tabs = $('.tabs li');
tabs.on('click', function() {
    var indx = tabs.removeClass('box_current').index(this);
    $(this).addClass('box_current');

    $('.tabs_box').eq(indx).fadeIn(150)
        .siblings('.tabs_box').hide();
});
```